Failed to expose service when use Cilium and Kubernetes Gateway API
I am using Cilium and Kubernetes Gateway API in Amazon EKS.
I am trying to expose one of my service (Goldilocks in this case at hm-goldilocks-dashboard.production-hm-goldilocks.svc:80) at https://hm-goldilocks.internal.mydomain.com
Here is my setup:
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: staging-lets-encrypt-cluster-issuer
  namespace: production-hm-cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    email: me@mydomain.com
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: staging-lets-encrypt-cluster-issuer-account-secret
    solvers:
      - selector:
          dnsZones:
            - internal.mydomain.com
        dns01:
          route53:
            region: us-west-2
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: staging-hm-cilium-gateway-certificate
  namespace: production-hm-gateway-api
spec:
  commonName: "*.internal.mydomain.com"
  secretName: staging-hm-cilium-gateway-certificate
  dnsNames:
    - "*.internal.mydomain.com"
  issuerRef:
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    name: staging-lets-encrypt-cluster-issuer
  # https://letsencrypt.org/certificates
  privateKey:
    algorithm: ECDSA
    size: 384
    rotationPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: hm-cilium-gateway
  namespace: production-hm-gateway-api
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: hm-cilium-gateway
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: production-hm-gateway-api
spec:
  gatewayClassName: cilium
  infrastructure:
    annotations:
      # https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/latest/guide/service/annotations
      # https://cloud-provider-aws.sigs.k8s.io/service_controller
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: subnet-xx,subnet-xx,subnet-xx,subnet-xx
  listeners:
    - name: http
      protocol: HTTP
      hostname: "*.internal.mydomain.com"
      port: 80
      allowedRoutes:
        namespaces:
          from: All
    - name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
      hostname: "*.internal.mydomain.com"
      port: 443
      allowedRoutes:
        namespaces:
          from: All
      tls:
        mode: Terminate
        certificateRefs:
          - kind: Secret
            name: staging-hm-cilium-gateway-certificate
            namespace: production-hm-gateway-api
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: hm-goldilocks-http-httproute
  namespace: production-hm-goldilocks
spec:
  parentRefs:
    - name: hm-cilium-gateway
      namespace: production-hm-gateway-api
      sectionName: http
  hostnames:
    - hm-goldilocks.internal.mydomain.com
  rules:
    - filters:
      - type: RequestRedirect
        requestRedirect:
          scheme: https
          port: 443
---
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: hm-goldilocks-https-httproute
  namespace: production-hm-goldilocks
spec:
  parentRefs:
    - name: hm-cilium-gateway
      namespace: production-hm-gateway-api
      sectionName: https
  hostnames:
    - hm-goldilocks.internal.mydomain.com
  rules:
    - matches:
      - path:
          type: PathPrefix
          value: /
      backendRefs:
        - name: hm-goldilocks-dashboard
          namespace: production-hm-goldilocks
          kind: Service
          port: 80

I can see that External DNS successfully registered with Route 53.

And Gateway's corresponding Load Balancer:

Here is my Gateway status:
➜ kubectl describe gateway hm-cilium-gateway -n production-hm-gateway-api
Name:         hm-cilium-gateway
Namespace:    production-hm-gateway-api
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/name=hm-cilium-gateway
              app.kubernetes.io/part-of=production-hm-gateway-api
              argocd.argoproj.io/instance=hm-gateway-api
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
Kind:         Gateway
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2024-08-01T21:07:08Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    1237234
  UID:                 c17f7a60-38ff-462a-90c6-b725066068c5
Spec:
  Gateway Class Name:  cilium
  Infrastructure:
    Annotations:
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal:    true
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets:     subnet-xx,subnet-xx,subnet-xx,subnet-xx
      service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type:        nlb
  Listeners:
    Allowed Routes:
      Namespaces:
        From:  All
    Hostname:  *.internal.mydomain.com
    Name:      http
    Port:      80
    Protocol:  HTTP
    Allowed Routes:
      Namespaces:
        From:  All
    Hostname:  *.internal.mydomain.com
    Name:      https
    Port:      443
    Protocol:  HTTPS
    Tls:
      Certificate Refs:
        Group:
        Kind:       Secret
        Name:       staging-hm-cilium-gateway-certificate
        Namespace:  production-hm-gateway-api
      Mode:         Terminate
Status:
  Addresses:
    Type:   Hostname
    Value:  aa3ff376273144bd089a876b9417e2fd-3fadba626fbed2b5.elb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:07:08Z
    Message:               Gateway successfully scheduled
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                Accepted
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Accepted
    Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:07:12Z
    Message:               Gateway successfully reconciled
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                Programmed
    Status:                True
    Type:                  Programmed
  Listeners:
    Attached Routes:  1
    Conditions:
      Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
      Message:               Listener Programmed
      Observed Generation:   1
      Reason:                Programmed
      Status:                True
      Type:                  Programmed
      Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
      Message:               Listener Accepted
      Observed Generation:   1
      Reason:                Accepted
      Status:                True
      Type:                  Accepted
      Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
      Message:               Resolved Refs
      Reason:                ResolvedRefs
      Status:                True
      Type:                  ResolvedRefs
    Name:                    http
    Supported Kinds:
      Group:          gateway.networking.k8s.io
      Kind:           HTTPRoute
    Attached Routes:  1
    Conditions:
      Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
      Message:               Listener Programmed
      Observed Generation:   1
      Reason:                Programmed
      Status:                True
      Type:                  Programmed
      Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
      Message:               Listener Accepted
      Observed Generation:   1
      Reason:                Accepted
      Status:                True
      Type:                  Accepted
      Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
      Message:               Resolved Refs
      Reason:                ResolvedRefs
      Status:                True
      Type:                  ResolvedRefs
    Name:                    https
    Supported Kinds:
      Group:  gateway.networking.k8s.io
      Kind:   HTTPRoute
Events:       <none>

My http HTTPRoute status:
➜ kubectl describe httproute hm-goldilocks-http-httproute -n production-hm-goldilocks
Name:         hm-goldilocks-http-httproute
Namespace:    production-hm-goldilocks
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/name=hm-goldilocks-http-httproute
              app.kubernetes.io/part-of=production-hm-goldilocks
              argocd.argoproj.io/instance=hm-goldilocks
Annotations:  argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync
API Version:  gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
Kind:         HTTPRoute
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    1237228
  UID:                 33184787-1469-473f-85f7-4e2d5df491d4
Spec:
  Hostnames:
    hm-goldilocks.internal.mydomain.com
  Parent Refs:
    Group:         gateway.networking.k8s.io
    Kind:          Gateway
    Name:          hm-cilium-gateway
    Namespace:     production-hm-gateway-api
    Section Name:  http
  Rules:
    Filters:
      Request Redirect:
        Port:         443
        Scheme:       https
        Status Code:  302
      Type:           RequestRedirect
    Matches:
      Path:
        Type:   PathPrefix
        Value:  /
Status:
  Parents:
    Conditions:
      Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
      Message:               Accepted HTTPRoute
      Observed Generation:   1
      Reason:                Accepted
      Status:                True
      Type:                  Accepted
      Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
      Message:               Service reference is valid
      Observed Generation:   1
      Reason:                ResolvedRefs
      Status:                True
      Type:                  ResolvedRefs
    Controller Name:         io.cilium/gateway-controller
    Parent Ref:
      Group:         gateway.networking.k8s.io
      Kind:          Gateway
      Name:          hm-cilium-gateway
      Namespace:     production-hm-gateway-api
      Section Name:  http
Events:              <none>

My https HTTPRoute status:
➜ kubectl describe httproute hm-goldilocks-https-httproute -n production-hm-goldilocks
Name:         hm-goldilocks-https-httproute
Namespace:    production-hm-goldilocks
Labels:       app.kubernetes.io/name=hm-goldilocks-https-httproute
              app.kubernetes.io/part-of=production-hm-goldilocks
              argocd.argoproj.io/instance=hm-goldilocks
Annotations:  argocd.argoproj.io/hook: PostSync
API Version:  gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
Kind:         HTTPRoute
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    1237227
  UID:                 af2c2c67-4ff4-4c5d-963f-0c2c6222b04f
Spec:
  Hostnames:
    hm-goldilocks.internal.mydomain.com
  Parent Refs:
    Group:         gateway.networking.k8s.io
    Kind:          Gateway
    Name:          hm-cilium-gateway
    Namespace:     production-hm-gateway-api
    Section Name:  https
  Rules:
    Backend Refs:
      Group:
      Kind:       Service
      Name:       hm-goldilocks-dashboard
      Namespace:  production-hm-goldilocks
      Port:       80
      Weight:     1
    Matches:
      Path:
        Type:   PathPrefix
        Value:  /
Status:
  Parents:
    Conditions:
      Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
      Message:               Accepted HTTPRoute
      Observed Generation:   1
      Reason:                Accepted
      Status:                True
      Type:                  Accepted
      Last Transition Time:  2024-08-01T21:41:06Z
      Message:               Service reference is valid
      Observed Generation:   1
      Reason:                ResolvedRefs
      Status:                True
      Type:                  ResolvedRefs
    Controller Name:         io.cilium/gateway-controller
    Parent Ref:
      Group:         gateway.networking.k8s.io
      Kind:          Gateway
      Name:          hm-cilium-gateway
      Namespace:     production-hm-gateway-api
      Section Name:  https
Events:              <none>

I can see http redirects to https, however, the https failed to point the Service in the Kubernetes:

My Cilium Helm values.yaml
eni:
  enabled: true
ipam:
  mode: eni
egressMasqueradeInterfaces: eth0
routingMode: native
kubeProxyReplacement: true
k8sServiceHost: xx.gr7.us-west-2.eks.amazonaws.com
k8sServicePort: 443
rollOutCiliumPods: true
operator:
  enabled: true
  rollOutPods: true
l7Proxy: true
gatewayAPI:
  enabled: true
  gatewayClass:
    create: "true"
hubble:
  enabled: true
  relay:
    enabled: true
  ui:
    enabled: true

Cilium Version
➜ cilium version --helm-release-name=hm-cilium --namespace=production-hm-cilium
cilium-cli: v0.16.13 compiled with go1.22.5 on darwin/arm64
cilium image (default): v1.15.6
cilium image (stable): v1.16.0
cilium image (running): 1.15.7

Kubernetes Version
➜ kubectl version
Client Version: v1.30.0
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.30.2-eks-db838b0

Any guide would be appreciate, thanks!
